I want to implement Corrado Su option pricing model. To get implied skew, implied kurtosis and IV from market data what numerical method should I use?
I want to implement Corrado Su option pricing model. To get implied skew, implied kurtosis and IV from market data what numerical method should I use? Should i take three options pair and calculate their skewness, kurtosis and Iv or the entire option chain?

You need first of all to have a smooth implied volatility skew to calculate the slope and convexity of the IV skew. See this post for more details: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/33204/relationship-between-implied-volatility-curve-derivatives-and-the-underlyings-m/81200#81200
